# Android How to get exact coordinate x and y values of image from the screen

Tags: android, image, position, touch, coordinate

I have one image of remote on screen,i want to when i click on any particular button at that time any particular event occurs,means image have some buttons when i exact touch on button held on in this image at that time occurs any events,i how to get position this button held on only image,and screen point x and y also change in different screen. i know `getX()` and `getY()' used to find touch position but how to get any particular position inside the image ,please help me quickly,thanks in advance.

[image: see in the image ,when i touch on middle of image at that time any event ocurrs]

see in the image ,when i touch on middle of image at that time any event ocurrs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
anchorView.getLocationOnScreen(location);
```

location is an array:

```
 int location[] = new int[2];
```

anchorView is your view.

So your function might look like:

```
public getLocation(View anchorView){
 int location[] = new int[2];
 anchorView.getLocationOnScreen(location);

}
```

And if you want to display a different view at that location just do:

```
 yourView.showAtLocation(anchorView, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 
                location[0], location[1] + anchorView.getHeight());
```

Also please note that you can manipulate the values in location[0] and location[1]. Good Luck :)

#### Edit

Here is a complete example, I use it to display a fragment below a button, this process takes place as soon as the button is clicked:

```
public void showPopup(View anchorView) {

        View popupView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popup_layout, null);

        popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, 
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


        Button proceed = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button cancel = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.button2);

        cb = (CheckBox)popupView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1); 

        proceed.setOnClickListener(onProceed); 
        cancel.setOnClickListener(onCan); 

        popupWindow.setFocusable(true);


        popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable());

        int location[] = new int[2];


        anchorView.getLocationOnScreen(location);

        popupWindow.showAtLocation(anchorView, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 
                location[0], location[1] + anchorView.getHeight());

    }
```

The above will result in a popup, just beneath the view clicked.

popup_layout is the XML layout file which will be inflated.

Comment: where to call this method ?

Comment: Depends on where you need it!!

Comment: you give some examples of it

Comment: Edited my answer, you can check it in the edit section.

Comment: but i have only one image of  remote and image have picture of button,not original button it is only image  ,so how i can find their position

Comment: Replace button with an ImageView above?

Comment: one minute i share image

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51716/discussion-between-nune-chai-and-nikiigeniusdev)